# Flutter how to add a button in a list view that persists after scrolling to a certain point..

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter

How would I create the shuffle play button shown here: https://media.giphy.com/media/25a17rL4Wm89idzPib/giphy.gif in flutter? Is there a specific widget or library I could utilize? Anything helps thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NestedScrollView with a SliverPersistentHeader as one of the widgets inside the array of headerSliverBuilder, to achieve the effect of persisting the header after you scroll up.

You can refer to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) for the same